# Spring Integration : How to check whether the input wsdl message is valid?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

I want to call a web services with Spring Integration. I have a soap message in a java String, and I want to validate it against the wsdl, before sending it to the external soap endpoint.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You don't do that against the whole WSDL, because one requests is not about contract and transport description. See `PayloadValidatingInterceptor`, which can be supplied with an XSD schema and injected into the `AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway`.

See more in docs:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/docs/current/reference/html/#_code_payloadvalidatinginterceptor_code